# R Shiny - Multiple radioButtons with same id / adding headers to groups of radioButtons

Tags: r, shiny

**WHAT I AM TRYING TO ACHIEVE:**

Add different headers on the different groups of radio buttons. I did it by creating two `radioButtons` widgets with the same id and different labels.

**PROBLEM:**

- When I run the script, Option D is selected and corresponding output show. WELL AND GOOD
- When I select any other option, it is selected and corresponding output show. AGAIN WELL AND GOOD
- ***When I try to select Option D again, it gets selected BUT the corresponding output does not show in the main panel. ***

**MWE:**

```
            library(shiny)

            ui <- fluidPage(
            sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                width = 3,
                radioButtons("aspect","Structure",
                            choices = list("Option A" = "size",
                                            "Option B" = "coh",
                                            "Option C" = "bound")
                ),
                hr(),
                radioButtons("aspect","Composition",
                            choices = list("Option D" = "div")
                )
                ),
                mainPanel(
                width = 9,
                fluidRow(
                    h3(textOutput("aboutText"))
                )
                )
            )
            )

            server <- function (input, output){
            aspectDesc <- reactive({
                switch(input$aspect,
                    size = "Alpha",
                    coh = " Beta",
                    bound = "Charlie",
                    div = "Delta")
            })
            output$aboutText <- renderText({paste("Text about ", aspectDesc())})


            }

            shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

- I removed the second RadioButtons widget and moved Option D to the first widget. It works fine. But I can not add the different headers.
- I have looked up how to group different radioButtons together but could not find anything substantial
- I set up the same id on two different radioButtons( which I did by accident) and at least I could select ONLY one option ( the way I wanted it).

I am totally at a loss what I am missing out. Although it seems to be a trivial issue.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You SHOULD NOT use the same id for two different widgets in shiny. In this specific case, I'd expect aspectDesc's switch to receive two different answers (not sure), what could be causing the problem. I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but you should use always use unique ids.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is Option A, Option B, and Option C to have same header and Option D to have a separate header. BUT the user can select only one of the 4 options. Does this make sense?

Comment: I have just tried doing the same, because I wanted one button per row, with other text to its right. Like urwaCFC, I found that Shiny won't pass values from the second group of buttons. Ricardo says don't use the same ID for two different widgets; but you have to in order that the browser keeps at most one button turned on. This has been part of HTML form design ever since the first days of the web, and Shiny ought to allow for it.

Answer (score 1):

After some labor, I've found this solution.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      width = 3,
      radioButtons("aspect1","Structure",
                   choices = list("Option A" = "size",
                                  "Option B" = "coh",
                                  "Option C" = "bound"),
                   selected = character(0)
      ),
      hr(),
      radioButtons("aspect2","Composition",
                   choices = list("Option D" = "div")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      width = 9,
      fluidRow(
        h3(textOutput("aboutText"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function (input, output, session){

  aspectDesc <- reactiveVal("Delta")

  onclick("aspect1", {
    updateRadioButtons(session, "aspect2", choices = list("Option D" = "div"), 
                       selected = character(0))
    aspectDesc(switch(input$aspect1,
                      size = "Alpha",
                      coh = " Beta",
                      bound = "Charlie"))
  })
  onclick("aspect2",{
      updateRadioButtons(session, "aspect1", 
                         choices = list("Option A" = "size",
                                        "Option B" = "coh",
                                        "Option C" = "bound"), 
                         selected = character(0))
    aspectDesc("Delta")
  })

  output$aboutText <- renderText({paste("Text about ", aspectDesc())})

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: THIS seems to work. Would you able to point out the reason why my code is not working. The logic seems to be correct. The implementation works when the app is fired. But later it kinda stops responding to user radiobutton selection.

Comment: also though your code works, I am sorry I didnot get the complete logic. Can you add a couple of lines about it.

Comment: do you think this is something that should be opened up as an issue on shiny github. OR is there something wrong with my logic/implementation.

Comment: @urwaCFC You cannot use the same id for two inputs. That's why your implementation doesn't work, but I'm not able to explain what happens exactly. My implementation is not hard to understand: when you click on a radio button, the click is detected by `onclick` and this triggers the update of the radio buttons (`updateRadioButtons`), with `selected=character(0)` to clean the selections. The point I don't understand is that I had to rewrite `choices` in the update. I hope my English is clear enough...

Comment: @urwaCFC Also, instead of using this way, you could use `selectizeInput` to do some groups, like this: https://imgur.com/BCYZLaA